# How to request permissions on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/permissions?tabs=android) tutorial to request some permissions for my App using Xamarin.

Here is my code :

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Java.Security;
using Xamarin.Essentials;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {       

        public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndRequestLocationPermission()
        {
            var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                return status;

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied && DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.iOS)
            {
                // Prompt the user to turn on in settings
                // On iOS once a permission has been denied it may not be requested again from the application
                return status;
            }

            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>())
            {
                // Prompt the user with additional information as to why the permission is needed
            }

            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

            return status;
        }
    }
}
```

The code doesn't compile and keeps saying : **'PermissionStatus' is inaccessible due to its protection level**

I don't know which reference or package I have to add.

Does anybody know how to solve that please ? Thanks.

[image]

"Show Potentiel Fixes" suggests I replace **PermissionStatus** with **PermissionState** in Security.Permissions.PermissionState

[image]

Comment: Check your usings, perhaps `Java.Security` also has a `PermissionStatus` that is less accessible than the one from `Xamarin.Essentials`?

Comment: do you need `Java.Security`?  That is probably causing a conflict

Comment: Thanks @Jason and Cheesebaron for your suggestions. I removed **Java.Security** but I'm still getting the same compilation error.

Comment: what does "Show Potential Fixes" show?  And can you verify which namespace it thinks `PermissionStatus` is in?

Comment: @Jason "Show Potentiel Fixes" suggests I replace **PermissionStatus** with **PermissionState** in Security.Permissions.PermissionState. I added a screenshot.

Comment: `Essentials` does not have a `Security` namespace.  It sounds like it is still trying to use `Java.Security`.  I'd try removing that again, restarting VS, cleaning, and rebuilding.